# How to compress image using javascript and then send it to the PHP server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image-uploading

I want to compress image before uploading it to PHP Server using vanilla javascript. I currently use PHP Compression however I was wondering whether it can be compressed in clients side browser so that it might save time uploading the images. 
I will be using fetch API to interact with the server.

I have read the following answers in stack overflow.

[Compressing an image before sending it to the Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030269/compressing-an-image-before-sending-it-to-the-server)
[How to compress image size in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038250/how-to-compress-image-size-in-javascript)

**Also I want to make it using Vanilla Javascript and does not want to depend upon libraries.**

Comment: You could try gzipping (https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip) it, and measuring what the binary looks like at the other end. For myself, I decided against compression. I figured that the image compression inherent in the image file format itself is about as good as you are going to get

Comment: I think this might help you: [How to compress an image via Javascript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser)